# Invoking specialized std::move()

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, move-semantics, template-specialization

I am confused about how template argument deduction is taking place in the example below. I use the term ***invoke*** in the rest of this post to imply ***instantiate and invoke***.

I specialized `std::move()` for my custom type `my_type` and I observe that, for an instance `x` of type `my_type`:

1. `std::move(x)` continues to invoke the generic template
2. `std::move(static_cast<my_type&&>(x))` or `std::move(std::forward(x))` invokes the specialization
3. In the absence of my specialization, all of the above calls invoke the generic template

My questions are:

- Why does the call in item #1 above not invoke the specialization?
- In the absence of the specialization, how do the calls in items #1 and #2 behave the same?

Here is the entire code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<utility>

struct my_type
{
    int x;
};

namespace std
{

// This is the std::move() definition in the preprocessor output:
//
// template <class _Tp>
// inline __attribute__ ((__visibility__("hidden"), __always_inline__)) constexpr
// typename remove_reference<_Tp>::type&&
// move(_Tp&& __t) noexcept
// {
//     typedef typename remove_reference<_Tp>::type _Up;
//     return static_cast<_Up&&>(__t);
// }

// This is std::move() specialized for my_type
template<>
inline
typename std::remove_reference<my_type>::type&&
move<my_type>(my_type&& t) noexcept
{
    std::cout << "Invoke std::move() specialization\n";
    return static_cast<typename remove_reference<my_type>::type&&>(t);
}

} // namespace std

int main()
{
  auto a = my_type();

  std::cout << "Execute 'auto b = std::move(a);'\n";
  auto b = std::move(a); // Invokes the generic template

  std::cout << "Execute 'auto c = std::move(static_cast<my_type&&>(a));'\n";
  auto c = std::move(static_cast<my_type&&>(a)); // Invokes the specialization

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Execute 'auto b = std::move(a);'
Execute 'auto c = std::move(static_cast<my_type&&>(a));'
Invoke std::move() specialization
```

Comment: Why are you specializing `std::move`?  If you want your toe to be movable just provide a move constructor and move assignment operator.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I agree that the custom move constructor and assignment operator is the proper way to go. But regardless, I cannot explain what I am observing. That's why I posted the question.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I think toes are already movable :-)

Comment: @AndyG What is a toe?

Comment: @ACE: It's one of those wiggly things attached to your foot ;-)

Comment: It all started when @NathanOliver made a typo :-))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `std::move(a)` the type of `a` is `my_type&`, not `my_type&&`. Therefore the generic `std::move` is a better match because it can match exactly.

If you changed your overload of `move` to look like this:

```
inline
typename std::remove_reference<my_type>::type&&
move(my_type& t) noexcept
{
    std::cout << "Invoke std::move() specialization\n";
    return static_cast<typename remove_reference<my_type>::type&&>(t);
}
```

Then it would appropriately get called (but the the generic one would get called for `std::move(static_cast<my_type&&>(a));`)

This happens because the [generic definition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) looks like this:

```
template< class T >
constexpr typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& move( T&& t );
```

That `T&&` is key. In the context of type deduction it can bind to both `my_type&`, `my_type&&` or any cv (`const` or `volatile`) variation. This is why in the absence of the specialization it's able to invoke the generic version for both calls.

So to really cover all bases, you'll need more than one overload. Probably, though, you'd be better off with a `custom_move` constrained for your type.

Comment: 1. if `a` is `my_type&` and ***not*** `my_type&&`, then why/how does it bind to the generic move template, which expects `T&&` and not `T&`
2. I did try to overload `move` with `my_type&` but I the compiler errored about not finding a matching template to specialize:
`(aka 'my_type &&(my_type &&) noexcept') against ... (aka 'my_type &&(my_type &) noexcept')`

Comment: @ACE:I answered 1) already in the post. "In the context of type deduction it can bind to both my_type&, my_type&& or any cv variation"

Comment: @ACE: Regarding 2) You probably didn't write it correctly (always prefer overloading to template specialization): Try this: https://wandbox.org/permlink/DlkWb1EyZWDZEOFA

Comment: Ah, you're overloading instead of template specializing

Comment: @ACE: The overloading is not necessary. It's just... weirder with template specialization: https://wandbox.org/permlink/M7VnfDdezjW0nhk6

Comment: @ACE: the argument to `std::move()` is a _forwarding reference_ which is deduced to the appropriate type. Your specialisation takes an _rvalue reference_ as argument. The type of an rvalue reference is clearly specified and not deduced as that of a forwarding reference.

Comment: @AndyG, yeah, I did make an error in my specialization for `my_type&`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So, your first problem is that any specialization of things in `std` must obey the requirements of the thing you are specializing.  Which means ... you aren't allowed to do anything different.

Second, the generic version of `std::move` uses perfect forwarding.  Specializations cannot.

```
#define SPEC_MOVE(X) \
template<> inline \
typename std::remove_reference<X>::type&& move<X>(X t) noexcept \
{ \
  std::cout << "Invoke std::move() specialization\n"; \
  return static_cast<typename remove_reference<X>::type&&>(t); \
}
SPEC_MOVE(my_type&&)
SPEC_MOVE(my_type&)
SPEC_MOVE(my_type const&)
SPEC_MOVE(my_type const&&)
SPEC_MOVE(my_type const volatile&&)
SPEC_MOVE(my_type const volatile&)
SPEC_MOVE(my_type volatile&)
SPEC_MOVE(my_type volatile&&)
```

That should do it.

This is a bad plan.

Comment: plus1 for `Specializations cannot use perfect forwarding`